# What are some JS library alternatives for Animate On Scroll (aos)?

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations, aos.js

I was designing my portfolio and came across aos. Can anyone list some of its alternatives?

Also are there some good libraries for such animation effects which are not just limited to scroll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are may libraries that you can use for scrolling animations. one of my favourite is ScrollMagic here is the link.

https://scrollmagic.io/

Go and just give it a try.

After that there is on emore same like AOS i.e SAL
here is the link for github repository and docs.
https://github.com/mciastek/sal